Flow | Email Sending
I'm setting up a screen flow where an email is triggered when the value of a picklist is X. So far, so good. However, if that email is approved, I need to send a second email. The question is: How do I make the flow execute the second action without repeating the first one? Otherwise, the email from the first condition (decision) will be repeated in the second decision (when the email is approved). In other words, I need to ensure that the second action is performed without repeating the first action (sending the first email). I thought using decisions would be enough, but it's not working for me. Do I need a subflow perhaps? Thanks in advance, regards!

Email approval will be a separate transaction and entry conditions for the second use case should be different from the first use case. The database (field value in a record) will be the only way you'll know which use case is running.

Create a Date field Email_1_Sent_Date__c to store the date the first email was sent. In your original screen flow where you send the first email, update this field with the date sent. You can also add to the decision criteria in this flow that Email_1_Sent_Date__c must be null to prevent this screen flow from ever re-sending the email.
I would also create a new Flow to send the second email rather than combining this into the first flow. If the "email approval" that you mention involves any field updates, this could be a record-triggered flow with the appropriate entry criteria.
